# Getting duplicate result objects in @ManyToMany relationship with Hibernate/JPA and play framework

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework

I'm using Play Framework v1.2.5 and JPA and Hibernate.

I have 2 models :

```
@Entity
public class MapTile extends Model {

    // ...

    @Required
    public Integer tileOrder;

    @Required
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<MapBuildingInfo> buildingsInfo;

    // ...
}

@Entity
public class MapBuildingInfo extends Model {

    // ...

    @Required
    public Integer buildingsCount;

    // ...
}
```

Let's say I have the following data :

```
MapTile :
    tileOrder: 1
    buildingsInfo: 
        - buildingsCount : 1
        - buildingsCount : 2

MapTile :
    tileOrder: 2
    buildingsInfo: 
        - buildingsCount : 3
        - buildingsCount : 4
```

I'm trying to retrieve (with only one query and joins) all `MapTiles` and their corresponding `MapBuildingInfos`.

Here is the query I use :

```
List<MapTile> list = MapTile.find("from MapTile tile left join fetch tile.buildingsInfo building").fetch();
```

And here are the results I have in my list :

```
list[0].tileOrder => 1
list[0].buildingsInfo[0].buildingsCount => 1
list[0].buildingsInfo[0].buildingsCount => 2

list[1].tileOrder => 1
list[1].buildingsInfo[0].buildingsCount => 1
list[1].buildingsInfo[0].buildingsCount => 2

list[2].tileOrder => 2
list[2].buildingsInfo[0].buildingsCount => 3
list[2].buildingsInfo[0].buildingsCount => 4

list[3].tileOrder => 2
list[3].buildingsInfo[0].buildingsCount => 3
list[3].buildingsInfo[0].buildingsCount => 4
```

Instead of just :

```
list[0].tileOrder => 1
list[0].buildingsInfo[0].buildingsCount => 1
list[0].buildingsInfo[0].buildingsCount => 2

list[1].tileOrder => 2
list[1].buildingsInfo[0].buildingsCount => 3
list[1].buildingsInfo[0].buildingsCount => 4
```

It seems that Hibernate/JPA is putting each result in a new MapTile object, so it creates a duplication. However he fills the `buildingsInfo` of `MapTile` correctly.

I don't understand why I get this result. Do you know what I could have done wrong ? Do you know if it's a bug from Hibernate/JPA ? Or an error from me ? How can I get the correct results ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to transform your query into :

`select distinct tile from MapTile tile left join fetch tile.buildingsInfo building`

Because of your fetch you create multiple lines and you need to tell hibernate to map this to the same instance.

Comment: Thank for your answer it seems to work! I didn't think it was that simple

Comment: @FabienHenon Thanks, it always help.